# Typescript wrong infer

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

In the following code, TS infer type of `y` as `string` while it's `undefined`. Is it possible to fix it without explicitly define `string|undefined` type for `y`?

```
const x: string[] = []
const y = x[0]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `"noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true` in tsconfig.json:

"Turning on *noUncheckedIndexedAccess* will add `undefined` to any un-declared field in the type": https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess

```
// with noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true

const x: string[] = [];

const y = x[0];

y;  // const y: string | undefined
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true#code/PTAEHcEsBcAtQHYHsCqCDGsCm6DWWATASQQKwA9CBBddLAZ3oF5oAnAVywCgv0kF60UOQBcoQa0gIA5gG0AuqCagFAbh58BQgJ5LhsgAzz1XbatCgQoTYNDaxEqdNAAfUO1JYAZlMJcgA)